# How to set onClickListener in Picasso

Tags: android, xml, onclicklistener, picasso

I'm an Android beginner and i'm building a soundboard app for fun and I'm using `Picasso` to display 2 columns of `ImageButton` side by side. Why Picasso ? Because with simple `ScrollView` and `ImageButton` my application was lagging a lot when scrolling down.

Anyway, I'm trying to play a sound when clicking on a picture but I can't find anything related to this on internet.

Here is my code :

**ImageListAdapter.java**

```
package com.kitbass.mastersynthetizer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;


public class ImageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private Integer[] imageResources;

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageButton mImageButton;
    }

    public ImageListAdapter(Context context, Integer[] imageUrls) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_item_image, imageUrls);

        this.context = context;
        this.imageResources = imageUrls;

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // ViewHolder pattern in play
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (null == convertView) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_image, parent, false);
            viewHolder.mImageButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_button);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Picasso
                .with(context)
                .load(imageResources[position])
                .fit()
                .centerInside()
                .into(viewHolder.mImageButton);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**PicassoActivity.java**

```
     GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.heenok_grid_view);
     gridView.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(PicassoActivity.this, imgResourcesHeenok));
     gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(PicassoActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
     });
```

**activity_picasso.xml**

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/heenok_grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="2" />
```

**listview_item_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/iv_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="121dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" />
```

Thanks !

**UPDATE** : The mistake was that I was using `ImageButton` instead of `ImageView`... That's why i wasn't able to have even a `Toast` working

Comment: You don't set the listener to Picasso, you set it on the View.

Comment: I added onItemClickListener to my GridView : 

`gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(PicassoActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });`

I doesn't show anything

Comment: `I'm trying to play a sound when clicking on a picture` You want to react to a picture being pressed but you add the listener to the Grid ?  Can I know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i would do a few things differently for your adapter class recycle your views using the ViewHolder Pattern:

change your xml to:

1. add an id
2. remove the onClick method call

as per:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/iv_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="121dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>
```

Then use the ViewHolder pattern in your adapter:

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private Integer[] imageResources;

    static class ViewHolder{
       ImageButton mImageButton;
    }

    public ImageListAdapter(Context context, Integer[] imageUrls) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_item_image, imageUrls);

        this.context = context;
        this.imageResources = imageUrls;

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // ViewHolder pattern in play
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (null == convertView) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_image, parent, false);
            viewHolder.mImageButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_button);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Picasso
                .with(context)
                .load(imageResources[position])
                .fit()
                .centerInside()
                .into(viewHolder.mImageButton);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

or switch to the more popular [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html)

then since you are using a `GridView` to handle clicks you need to add an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` in your Activity class:

```
mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){
      //... handle the sound playing here
      // onSoundButtonClick() ? maybe
    }

});
```

for all this you can find an example [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Good Luck and Happy coding!

Comment: I did as you said but can't even make a `Toast` appear? Is that due to my Adapter extending `ArrayAdapter` instead of `BaseAdapter`? I'll update my post to show the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update your **listview_item_image.xml** as below:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/image_button"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="121dp"
       android:background="@null"
       android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>
   ```
2. Update **ImageListAdapter** method **getView()** as:

   ```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       if (null == convertView) {
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_image, parent, false);
       }

       ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_button);

       Picasso
           .with(context)
           .load(imageResources[position])
           .fit()
           .centerInside()
           .into(imageButton);

       return convertView;
   }
   ```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Save my time